# JOIN некоторых строк к таблице как новых столбцов

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет. Предположим есть таблица:

```
| id | item |
-------------
|  1 |  egg |
```

Довольно не большая, но для примера сойдет.

Есть вторая таблица:

```
| id | item_id | shape | corners |
----------------------------------
|  1 |       1 | round |       0 |
|  2 |       1 |  cube |       4 |
```

Буду краток - вопрос:
Как получить следующую таблицу?

```
| id | item | round | cube |
----------------------------
|  1 |  egg |     0 |    4 |
```

З.Ы. Соединение идет по `id <-> item_id`

Comment: Именно в таком виде - только через дополнительный `join`. Но где гарантия, что всегда будет только два поля? Можно немного переделать результат - в одной колонке список `shape`, в другой колонке - список `corners`. Это сделать можно через [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) А разделять их программно будете.

Comment: @BOPOH а насколько сильно много join'ов нагрузят запрос?

Comment: В разумных пределах ничего страшного не будет. Вот только это неправильный подход. Ведь насколько понимаю, у одного `item_id` будет две записи, у другого - три, а у десятого - все десять. Хотя если у одного `item_id` гарантировано будет только две записи, то, думаю, можно и через `join`\`ы сделать.

Comment: @BOPOH тут появляется новая проблема.. я не знаю сколько будет этих колонок, для одного это будет просто `round`, для второго и `round` и `cube`, а для третьего их не будет вообще, а для четвертого будет вообще 3 колонки не похожие на предыдущие и т.д.

Comment: А что мешает на клиенте (в данном случае на php) нужные поля получать? Я же говорю - можно через `GROUP_CONCAT` в одном поле получить список `shape`, в другом поле - список `corners` ([пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1fa2/1)), а в php из этих полей генерируете нужный вам результат через [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). Правда и здесь результат не всегда [желаемый](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7c9f/1). Проще на клиенте (php) все собирать

Answer (score 1):

Как говорит @BOPOH можно использовать `JOIN`, но единствено верным будет использование `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(t2.shape = ''', shape, ''', t2.corners, NULL)) AS ', shape))
INTO @pivot_sql
FROM table2;

SET @pivot_sql = CONCAT('SELECT t1.id, t1.item, ', @pivot_sql, ' 
                   FROM Table1 t1
                   LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.item_id
                   GROUP BY t1.id, t1.item');

PREPARE stmt FROM @pivot_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**UPDATE** Как отметили в комментариях,  лучше собирать необходимый запрос на клиенте.

Comment: Сижу пол часа уже пытаюсь разобраться... Что будет в `@pivot_sql`?

Comment: @igolka97 после первого `SELECT` в переменной будет строка вида: `MAX(IF(t2.shape = 'значение 1 поля shape', t2.corners, NULL) as 'значение 1 поля shape', MAX(IF(t2.shape = 'значение 2 поля shape', t2.corners, NULL) as 'значение 2 поля shape', ... , MAX(IF(t2.shape = 'значение N поля shape', t2.corners, NULL) as 'значение N поля shape'`. После второго `SELECT` будет готовый запрос. Вообще, поставьте после каждого изменения `SELECT @pivot_SQL` и думаю разберетесь.

Comment: А зачем тогда max()?

Comment: @igolka97 потому, как второй `SELECT` вернет две записи в одной значение `shape` будет равно `round ` а в во второй нет. Соответственно будет два значения `NULL` и `0`, и тут с помощью группировки `MAX()` вернет большее значение, а именно `0`.

Comment: @igolka97 попробуйте убрать из запроса `GROUP BY t1.id, t1.item` и поймете в чем дело.

Comment: @VitalyKolyada ааа, никогда бы не додумался)

Comment: В чем смысл генерировать запрос на сервере, а не на клиенте? При том, что какие именно колонки вернутся и какие в них данные следует искать не совсем понятно. При том, что необходимо дополнительно контролировать данные для shape: инъекции, длина имени псевдонима и т.д. / Этот метод оригинальный и даже может быть где-то использован, но уж точно правильным (в противовес join'у), тем более единственно правильным он не является.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov согласен с вами, лучше собирать запрос на клиенте.

Comment: @YuraIvanov @VitalyKolyada в моем случае собирать данные на клиенте - не правильный подход. Собирать данные на клиенте, это значит  по одному запросу для каждого цикла `foreach` тоесть для каждого результата-строки из первой таблицы, а строк этих может быть очень много:( поэтому мое решение  - множественный join. К тому же зачем делать это на клиенте нагружая  mysql сервер  запросами, когда все это можно сделать и средствами mysql, да еще и не нагружая клиент многочисленными циклами `foreach`?

Comment: Система слишком сложная у меня) поэтому стараюсь по максимуму разгрузить mysql сервер, и перенести часть логики и алгоритмов с  `php` на `mysql`

Comment: @igolka97, вы не поняли. На клиенте необходимо собирать **текст запроса**, а не данные в циклах. Чтобы собрать запрос вам нужно будет узнать какие есть данные во второй таблице (точнее в колонке shape). А результирующий запрос будет один.

Answer (score 1):

можно конечно так

```
SELECT 
    a1.id,
    a1.item,
    (SELECT corners from table2 where item_id = a1.id limit 0, 1) as round,       
    (SELECT corners from table2 where item_id = a1.id limit 1, 1) as cube 
    from(
        SELECT id, item  from table1
    ) as a1
```

Так будет отображено, но вообщето зачем оно вам нужно?

не лучше ли выбирать данные так как они есть и просто при отображении манипулировать ими? (т.е выбрали данные с помощью JOIN а когда обрабатываете заносите в массив и все...у вас данные готовые к работе)

На клиенте тоже можно манипулирвоать данными, как писали выше, но тут какбы вопрос (зачем выбирать данные из базы которые не нужны?), если у вас данные на клиенте часто нужно будет отображаться то одни то другие динамически, то чтобы не делать выборки из базы туда сюда...может и имеет смысл выбирать кучу и уже на клиенте ее отобажать , если задача такого не предусматривает то я бы не стал на клиенте это делать.